# WSUS Server limits to 12 clients

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-update

I'm having an issue where my WSUS Server (Windows 2012 R2) only reports 12 clients.  I've modified the local group policy of each client host to contact the WSUS server, but only 12 show under "All Computers".  If I attempt to add a 13th client, the server will bump one of the last 12 (I cannot tell if it's the previously added client, FIFO, or random).

Did I miss something in setup of the server or is it an issue with WSUS?  I followed the basic/default setup for the installation of WSUS and nothing else is running on the server.

I've tried finding anything on the issue but this seems like I'm the only one so I'm sure its a misconfiguration on my part.

Thank you for advice and help...
David

Comment: Probably duplicate client IDs.  You might try [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-WSUS-Authorization-2e26d1b0) (first result of a Google search, I've never used it myself).  If you need more information or if it doesn't work, ask on Server Fault; this is off-topic here.

Comment: This looks like a good possibility!  The machine was build from a VM template and DOES show as updates "Managed by your systems administrator".  When I get a moment, I'll give the suggestion a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  :-\  Any other suggestions or where to look in the logs?

Comment: Turns out this did work.  I'm starting to see my WSUS clients registering with my WSUS server.  I greatly appreciate your help in your suggestion and pointing me to the proper place to search/submit.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was not associated with a 12 client limit - either with server or WSUS application.  I was able to apply the suggestion above and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There SusClientId are duplicated.
You will need to run on every client the following script:

```
net stop wuauserv 
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v PingID /f 
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v AccountDomainSid /f 
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientId /f  
reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientIDValidation /f 
net start wuauserv 
wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow 
pause
```

[Reference](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-WSUS-Authorization-2e26d1b0)